# casting boolean type with doctrine 2 DQL

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine entity A which has a field 'attendance' of type boolean. The values for this field are stored as t and f in postgres. **I want to write a DQL which will give me the field value as 1 or 0**. I can do the same in SQL with postgressql cast statement like below :

```
"select attendance::int from class where student = 1"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine extensions provides [CAST function](https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions#dql-functions). Another option is [NativeQuery](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class) or pure SQL query (if you don't need mapping).